# How can we get xlsx files from share point to data lake gen 1 using logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I tried using ADF and failed, So I'm using logic app.
In logic app I'm able to get data from SharePoint but can not upload file into datalake.
I'm using following actions in logic app

1. List files in SharePoint
2. Get file content in SharePoint
3. Upload file in dala lake - this is not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

While uploading the file you need to mention the File Name in the File path after '/'.

Here is how it worked for me. Below is my workflow
[image]

---

**Run Details :**

[image]

---

**In Sharepoint :**
[image]

---

**In DataLake :**

[image]